# How do I stop testing in Python unittest tearDown()?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've got a large number of tests written using Python `unittest` (Python 2.7.8) as a large `TestSuite`.  Many of these tests invoke other programs.  Sometimes these other programs dump core.  When they do, I want to discover that and ensure the test fails.  If some number of cores are dumped, I want to abort the entire test environment and exit rather than continuing: my total test suite has >6000 tests and if everything is dumping core it's useless (and dangerous: disk space etc.) to continue.

In order to ensure we look for coredumps after every test (so I have the best possible idea of what program/invocation dumped core) I decided to look for cores in `tearDown()`, which I am doing successfully.  If I find a core, I can run an assert variant in `tearDown()` to specify that the test failed.

But I can't figure out how to just give up on all my testing completely from within `tearDown()` if I find too many cores.  I even tried to run `sys.exit("too many cores")`, but unittest `case.py` catches every exception thrown by `tearDown()` except `KeyboardInterrupt` (if I try to raise that by hand my script hangs until I do a real `^C`).

I thought about trying to call `stop()`, but this is a method on the result and I can't find any way to get access to the result object from within `tearDown()` (!).

So far my only option seems to be to invoke `os._exit()` which is really annoying because it keeps any results from being reported at all!

Is there really no facility in Python `unittest.TestCase` to tell the test environment to just stop right now, generate what results you have but don't run anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check how many cores have been dumped in `setUp()`? If so, you could just call [`self.skipTest('Too many cores dumped.')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.skipTest) when things get bad.

If you don't want to look for cores in `setUp()`, you could probably use a class variable to hold the core dump count and check that instead.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, although it still means I'm running all the rest of the testcases, they're just skipping after setUp(). I did find a way to plumb the result object through to the test case using a class variable, so in `tearDown()` I invoke the result `stop()` method and that helps as well.  Very frustrating that unittest doesn't support this; indeed, it goes out of its way to block any way of doing it!

Comment: They wouldn't skip *after* `setUp()`, @MadScientist, if you put the check at the beginning of setUp(). If the check is inexpensive and near the beginning of `setUp()`, it seems like a reasonable compromise. You can also call `skipTest()` from within higher level set up methods to skip a whole group of tests.

Comment: By the way, @MadScientist, I wouldn't say that the unittest module goes out of its way to block your attempt to abort the run. I would say that it goes out of its way to avoid side effects from one test method affecting another. The short cuts you're trying to add will increase the risk of unstable tests. You have to decide if the speed improvement is worth the risk of getting incorrect results from a test run.

Comment: What I want is a way for a test case to tell the unittest environment that all is lost, and no further tests of any kind should be invoked and whatever cleanup is currently configured should be completed, then unittest should stop running tests.  Maybe it's just me but that doesn't seem like an unusual thing to want to be able to do within a test framework.  It doesn't appear that unittest provides any facility that allows this, at all.

Comment: Further, unittest actively goes out of its way to make this impossible for me to do any other way by catching all exceptions (I'm not saying it doesn't have a good reason for doing this, just that the fact that it's done makes it difficult/impossible for me to get the behavior I need that unittest doesn't provide).  When I said "after setUp()" I just meant that setUp() would be invoked for all 6,000+ tests that I already know that I don't want to run... I definitely would put the check at the beginning of setUp().

Comment: So far your `os._exit()` answer seems to be winning.  You’re right, this _is_ a sensible thing to ask for in our situation, where if a service isn't running there's no point to the rest of the tests, and I want the error message to be prominent at the end of the output, rather than lost amid later predictable failures.